# What is a weight vector in layman's terms?

Tags: representation-theory

I am trying to understand what a weight vector is but the [wikipedia is in greek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_%28representation_theory%29). What is the jist?

Comment: [This](http://translate.google.com/#el/en/) might help. :P

Comment: Do you know what an eigenvector is? A weight vector is an eigenvector simultaneously for a collection of linear operators instead of one linear operator.